# How to change Tracker so it can find numbers

Tags: nautilus, search, locate, tracker

I want/need to be able to search my files for number sequences (like order number and such). But after installing Tracker on Ubuntu 18.10 (with the dev. Pre-released updates (cosmic-proposed) on) I'm able to search with word but not with numbers.

Can you help me change this? Or is this not possible with Tracker?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use gsettings command:

> gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.FTS ignore-numbers false